# Accessing Spark Streaming Data pipelines. What option works best?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am looking for the best option to access data from Spark data pipelines. The scenario is as follows:

I am reading data from Kafka topics, creating a streaming dataframe which is then cleaned and being printed on the console. I need this data to be integrated with existing Python scripts which is doing all the data operations by Pandas. I have considered the following options:

1. Write streaming data to local memory (e.g. Hive Tables).
2. Use Spark Structured Streaming ForeachBatch Sink.

I want to mention that the data is to be read after a certain interval and there will be a real time data dashboard in the future with this data.

Please advise which will be the best approach to handle this scenario. Apologies if the question sounds too basic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you save data on Hive each time before accessing the newly streamed data through python scripts, the newly added hive partitions are required to be refreshed each time as well.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

Here are some disadvantages of having a hive for mentioned real-time scenarios.
https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-disadvantages-of-Apache-Hive#

Whereas, Using Spark Structured Streaming looks a better choice for the near-real-time experience.
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will definitely check them out.